# How can I create a unique ParseObject for each user of my Android App?

Tags: android, parse-platform

My app retrieves GPS location of where the user is every hour. If the user updates a list, then I either add or delete that item from the ParseCloud.

As of now, I instantiated a ParseObject

```
private ParseObject locationItem = new ParseObject("LocationInformation");
```

I then initialized Parse using my key and turn on analytics

```
Parse.initialize(this, "KEY", "KEY"); 
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

If the location is available (within the onLocationChanged method of the LocationListener), I add the latitude and longitude to the locationItem

```
locationItem.put("latitude", location.getLatitude()); 
locationItem.put("longitude", location.getLongitude()); 
locationItem.saveEventually();
```

I update the ParseCloud with the item and the key deletedItem or addItem so that I can include the location information with the add.

```
locationItem.put("addItem", blackListItem);
```

or 
    locationItem.put("deleteItem", blackListItem);
I call the same lat/long method to place it into the item and update it to the cloud.

Since I want all of these updates to be stored on a per-user basis, I want to know the proper method of doing so. I suspect I need to somehow employ the ParseUser class, but am confused as to how.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual where it covers Users and user table. On first config of the app, it should create a new parse user and then after that use one of several techniques to associate other data types to the new user.

Using Rest API and android, at a minimum you can use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475957/how-to-store-some-particular-data-for-some-particular-parse-user-in-android) to associate the user by including that user's oid in all the ACL objects contained in your "LocalInformation" class objects and by including the user's Token in the http headers when you POST/GET the "LocalInformation" type.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the user create a new account, or sign in with their facebook or twitter account, and then associate the ParseObject with the ParseUser.

Once you have the user sign in with a new account, or with their facebook or twitter account the ParseUser object will not be null.

```
final boolean isLoggedIn = ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null;  //isLoggedIn should be true
```

after that then simply create the object and associate it with the ParseUser.

```
ParseUser mUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); 

ParseObject mItem = new ParseObject("LocationInformation");
mItem.put("latitude", location.getLatitude()); 
mItem.put("longitude", location.getLongitude()); 
mItem.put("UniqueUser", mUser ); 
mItem.saveInBackground();
```

You use a query to find the object associated with a particular unique user.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("LocationInformation");
query.whereEqualTo("UniqueUser", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()); 

//if running this code on a background thread, otherwise use a callback
try
{
  //should be unique object associated with a user
  ParseObject mItem = query.getFirst(); 
}
catch( ParseException e )
{
//DEBEUG
}
```