# Trouble retrieving Parse data with ACL using REST API / JS

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform, titanium, acl

Issue:
I am creating records in my Parse.com custom object. Here is how my request / JSON payload looks like...

```
[INFO] :   {"message":"My record with ACL","ownerName":"Dude","ACL":{"77cUXY2h1T":{"read":true,"write":true}}}
```

Here is the response I get...

```
[INFO] :   {"createdAt":"2014-10-30T03:19:26.789Z","objectId":"0bcd7RfYf0"}
```

When I look at the record from my data browser, the ACL appears to be set correctly. I am logged in as the current user but when I query the records, I do not get the ones where I have ACL set up. I can still create records with no ACL and retrieve them fine. Did I not set something correctly or am I missing something?

Here is a screenshot of the data browser with ACL's setup. I have spent a lot of hours trying to figure this out and will appreciate any pointers / help. Thanks![image]

Comment: You might want to double check if the user is actually logged in right before the query. If that checks out then check your ACLs again, make sure it is correct.

Comment: Thanks @sarvesh. I am new to Parse so maybe I am not following it. If my app is able to create the record, doesn't that mean that my user is logged in and has a valid session? Also, when I look at the data browser, it shows the "username(username object id)", so it appears that the Parse ACL is setting up correctly. Is there some other way to check these? I am using REST API via JS to conduct all of this record creation / ACL setting.

Comment: When you make the query using the REST API are you sure you are passing the X-Parse-Session-Token header, this is returned by the login call? Any reason you can't use the JS SDK it would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: That did it @sarvesh. Thanks for your help. I have not tried using the JS SDK because I am using Titanium to write a mobile app. Titanium internally uses JS, and so using REST API was not too bad. Frankly though, I am not even sure if it will work with Titanium or not. Thanks again for your help. I will mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: Credit:@Sarvesh: If you are using REST API to create Parse records and setting ACL with them, you will need to include the X-Parse-Session-Token.

Addn'l info [how to store some particular data for some particular parse user in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475957/how-to-store-some-particular-data-for-some-particular-parse-user-in-android)

Comment: @turtle - SO did not allow me to acccept my own answer when I wrote it. I think it wanted me to wait two days before I accept it. I will try it again...but just so you know. Thanks!